# Are there transitions of mixed multipolarity in charged ions?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, multipole-expansion, atomic-clocks

In nuclear physics transitions with mixed multipolarity, ex. (M1+E2), play an important role due to d-wave admixture. I was wondering if analogous situation has ever been considered in atomic transitions.

For instance, from what I understand, $^3F_2 \rightarrow \;^3F_3$ transition has M1, E2, M3, E4 and M5 multipoles involved, but usually in literature people talk only about M1. Are M1$<$contributions just so weak that everybody neglect them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Transitions with mixed multipolarity typically indicate broken parity invariance in the eigenstates (unless I've got my symmetries wrong), normally coming from weak nuclear interactions, and that won't be present in atomic physics. With that in mind, can you clarify which types of transition you're thinking of on both sides of the aisle, with as much detail as possible?

Comment: Nuclear ex.: N to Delta transition has (M1+E2). Atomic ex.: Pr$^{9+}$ has transition $^3F_2 \rightarrow \; ^3F_3$, which should have 5 multipoles present, but only the leading one is discussed, ex. Safronova, M. S., et al. "Highly charged ions for atomic clocks, quantum information, and search for α variation." Physical review letters 113.3 (2014): 030801.

Comment: "...mixed multipolarity typically indicate broken parity invariance in the eigenstates..." - what's different in case with nuclear transitions? In both cases fermionic states are excited by spin=1 massless bosons...